# Map the values of array elements

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse, data-structures

```
public class EconomicModel {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[] StarTime = new int[20];
        int[] duration = new int[40];
        int[] TotalDuration = new int[40];
        int[] EndTime = new int[StarTime.length];
        int[] relinqtime = new int[20];

        int[] ResAllocRAM = {101,9,56,89,43,30,8,60,13,41,60, 20, 32,71,76,7,31,46,30,99 };


        StarTime[0] = 0;

        ExponentialDistribution exp = new ExponentialDistribution(4.0);
        for(int j = 1; j < 20; j++){
            StarTime[j] = (int)exp.sample() + 1+StarTime[j-1];

        }
            for(int k = 0; k < 20;k ++){
                duration[k] = 20 + (int)(Math.random() * ((120 - 10) + 1));

            }


            for(int k = 0; k < 20; k++){
                EndTime[k] = StarTime[k] + duration[k];

            }
            Random r = new Random();
            for (int i=0; i<20; i++){
                relinqtime[i] = r.nextInt((EndTime[i] - StarTime[i])+ StarTime[i] ) + StarTime[i];

            }
            for ( int j = 0; j<20; j++)
            for(int k =  StarTime[j]; k <= relinqtime[j]; k++){
                 TotalDuration[k]+= ResReqRAM[j];

            }
            }
            }
```

I have arrays called `StarTime`, `relinqtime`, `ResAllocRAM` and `TotalDuration`. I want to assign values to the indexes of array `TotalDuration` based on the other three arrays. Like if value of `StarTime[1]` is 5, value of `relinqtime[1]` is 8, value of  `ResAllocRAM[1]` is 9. I want that value `TotalDuration[5]`,`TotalDuration[6]`,`TotalDuration[7]` should be the value of `ResAllocRAM[1]`.

I tried the above code but it is giving exception bound error at line `TotalDuration[k]+= ResReqRAM[j];`

What should I do to map the values of these arrays and produce a new array as mentioned?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please format your question code better so it is readable without scrolling, show specific and literal error messages, and explain in more detail how you want the values to be calculated.

Comment: And please, indent your code properly, and respect the Java naming conventions.

Comment: Note: According to the Java language conventions, you should name variables with names that start with a lowercase letter, e.g. `endTime`, `startTime`, not `EndTime` and `StarTime` - uppercase letter at the beginning is reserved for types (classes, enums, interfaces).

Comment: Does anyone understand the requirements?

Comment: `r.nextInt(EndTime[i])` is a shortcut for `r.nextInt((EndTime[i] - StarTime[i])+ StarTime[i] )`

Comment: Its going bananas in the last double nested for loop, where the values of the arrays are used as array indices. But no, the algorithm to fill the values is not clear to me.

Answer (score 0):

Use a Map, it saves elements as Key, Value pair, remember keys should be unique.

```
Map<Integer, Integer> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
hashMap.put(TotalDuration[5], ResAllocRAM[1]); //put(key,value)
int value = hashMap.get(TotalDuration[5]); //it will return you value of ResAllocRAM[1]
```

simple [tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_map_interface.htm) for map

Comment: Can one key have multiple values?

Comment: @Sjs No. However, a value can be a Collection or Array and in that sense hold multiple values within itself.

Comment: for having multiple value for a key add arrays as values i.e. `Map<Integer, Integer[]> hashMap = new HashMap<>();`

Comment: detail example: `Map<Integer, Integer[]> hashMap = new HashMap<>(); Integer[] array = {12, 38, 49, 46}; Integer yourKey = 32; hashMap.put(yourKey, array);`

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the line as follows

`TotalDuration[k] = ResReqRAM[j];`

If you are trying to increment TotalDuration then set initial values to 0 as the TotalDuration array is empty when you are trying to assign in it